# I barely have free space in the system partition but I should have much more (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, ssd, disk-space, windirstat

At work I have a computer with two hard drives, a 60 GB SSD as the system partition and a 300GB HDD as a data partition.

The SSD is almost full or at least that's what I can see in the disk manager and the file explorer. But when I select all the files from the root of the SSD and I see the total size, it turns to be around 40 GB, which should give me more than 15 GB of available space. Of course in this selection I included the hidden files and the protected operating system files.

So, I have more than 15 GB in use but I don't know where they come from.

I tried some things to recover that space but without success. I disabled System Restore and the paging file.

What is even more strange is that I downloaded WinDirStat and surprisingly the program shows me that I have around 30% of free space on that partition.

I don't know what more to do and since this not my computer I cannot format the partition.

Here is a screenshot of the file explorer:

[image: File explorer show me I barely have free space]

And here is another one from WinDirStat:

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of windirstat and windows-explorer.

Comment: I added the screenshots.

Comment: Did you run WinDirStat "As Administrator"?  Have you tried running Windows Disk Cleanup utility to see what it says it taking up the space?

Comment: Agreed, this looks like its running on a limited account WinSxS and Installers could easily be 20GB but you wont be able to see or clean them without admin.

Comment: run TreeSizeFree (as admin): http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Comment: Well, I finally discover it thanks to cʜι 007. It was a permissions problem. When I selected all the files from the C drive I wasn't suming the size of the users folders since I didn't have permissions over them. I didn't know that without permissions I couldn't be able to get their size. So, granting permissions over the users folders gave me the right sum. Also, I didn't run WinDirStat as administrator, so the program wasn't grabing those sizes either.